# emberjs getEach method does not work as expected

Tags: ember.js

I have the following code which I expect to return [1000] but returns [undefined]:

```
this.get('details').getEach('gross_total')
```

But

```
this.get('details')[0].get('gross_total')
```

does work and returns 1000.

I am using rc3 right now. The same code in rc1 worked fine.

My persistence layer is taken from discourse. The relevant models are below. Invoice has_many details

```
App.Invoice = App.Model.extend App.Commentable,
  invoice_number: App.Attr('string')
  description: App.Attr('string')
  issue_date: App.Attr('date')
  due_date: App.Attr('date')
  contact: App.BelongsTo('App.Contact', "contacts")
  details: App.HasMany('App.InvoiceDetail', "detail_ids")
  payments: App.HasMany('App.Payment', "payment_ids")
  invoice_status: App.Attr('string')
  comments: App.HasMany('App.Comment', "comment_ids")

App.InvoiceDetail = App.Model.extend App.DestroyableChild,
  detail_no: App.Attr('int') 
  description: App.Attr('string') 
  quantity: App.Attr('float') 
  unit_price: App.Attr('currency') 
  consumption_tax_rate: App.Attr('float')
  vat_rate: App.Attr('float')
  discount_type: App.Attr('string')
  discount_value: App.Attr('currency')
  product: App.BelongsTo('App.Product', 'products')
```

Comment: Assuming this.get('details') is an array of records from the database, can you paste the code for the detail model definition ?

Comment: This is where it gets tricky and I'm not entirely show what to show. I have a custom implementation of persistence layer taken mostly from discourse. I've updated my question above, but I don't think it's all that helpful unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this issue when prototyping require.js use for loading my app. Using ember.js 1.0.0-rc.1.

I traced it down to having two ember.js script instances (each of which contains its own different Ember.META_KEY) which implied the illogical behavior.

So the answer seems to be to **make sure only a single ember.js copy is loaded** within the browser window context.