# emberjs get('lastObject') bug?

Tags: ember.js

I'm looping through an array using Ember.Array#lastObject property:

```
while (last = this.get('clickViews.lastObject')) {
  // perform some actions to last
  this.get('clickViews').removeObject(last);
}
```

When all objects from the clickViews array have been removed, this.get('clickViews.lastObject') still returns an object. Is there something wrong with how I'm getting 'lastObject' or removing objects from array?

Comment: did you try out the solution proposed in my answer? did it work?

Comment: @intuitivepixel thanks for checking up. The original problem was due to what I thought was a bug with Ember.Array. No matter how I iterated over the array, it wasn't working. I think what was happening was actually this: there was two versions of ember.js loaded within the browser window context due to cacheing problems. Please see this similar question from me before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16773229/emberjs-geteach-method-does-not-work-as-expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a cacheing problem with multiple versions of emberjs loaded within the browser window context, as similar to the answer to this question: [emberjs getEach method does not work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16773229/emberjs-geteach-method-does-not-work-as-expected)

I resolved problem by clearing browser history and rails precompiled tmp files.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should do it this way. See here for a working [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/axuzat/1/edit).

```
while (this.get('clickViews.lastObject') !== undefined) {
  // perform some actions to last
  this.get('clickViews').removeObject(this.get('clickViews.lastObject'));
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The example I gave was just illustrative of the loop; while looping I'm performing other actions to each object (I'll edit my example as accordingly). 'lastObject' or 'firstObject' doesn't return 'undefined', it seems to return whatever the last or first object was.

Comment: @SeanX.Yu see my updated answer maybe it works now for you, I've also added a pseudo jsbin:http://jsbin.com/axuzat/1/edit that shows it working.